# Exporting From Babylon.js or Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am attempting to take a babylon.js model in the .babylon format and export it to .obj or .stl (any other format readable by maya). I found no method to do this with babylon.js itself, however three.js has an save as obj function in its editor. The editor is able to load the babylon.js object fine, it displays it however when I attempt to save it, I get an empty file, this happens for any option other than geometry or scene.

Is there something I am missing that needs to be done in order to complete the export?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been fixed in the the dev branch. http://threejs.org/editor/ will be updated next week (15th).